# Creating multiple pages with a loop of 1 category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, categories

i need to make a loop for a single category.
Everything works fine, exept that i'm unable to split the page in multiple parts.

This is the LOOP of my page.
Output is fine, exept that navigation bar doesn't show, and simply adding to url a /page/2 it shows the first 2 posts.

```
            <?php query_posts('cat=179&posts_per_page=2'); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'morlottiTabs' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php morlottiTabs_posted_on(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <div class="entry-utility">
                    <?php morlottiTabs_posted_in(); ?>
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'morlottiTabs' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-utility -->
              </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            <?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
            <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'morlottiTabs' ) ); ?></div>
                                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'morlottiTabs' ) ); ?></div>
                            </div><!-- #nav-below -->

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it this way.  There are some other methods listed for pagination as well.

Reference: http://digwp.com/2009/08/wordpress-page-navigation/

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

---

**Edit:**

Would you want to try a different method?

Wordpress has their own method of pagination

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

```
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ) ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't help my problem. it's because i need to fix the "loop" itself, not the link to other pages... it seems that in every page i try to explore ( page/2, page/3 ) the loop restarts from the last post. The result is i'll get always the first # number of posts.

Comment: i simply edited the loop of category/archives without creating extra-pages

http://www.morlotti.com/category/wedding-stories-emotion-through-photographs

i'll fix the layout later :)